# My question is that i got an out of range error

Tags: c++

```
cout << "If you would like to find/replace or copy/paste, enter find or copy: " << endl;  
cin >> answer;    
cin.ignore();   
if(answer == "find"){   
  cout << "Enter substring to find: " << endl;   
  cin >> userInput2;   
  cin.ignore();   
  cout << "Do you want to find if/where the substring occurs, delete it, or replace it (find, delete, replace)? " << endl;   
  cin >> answer;   
  cin.ignore();   
  position = userInput.find(userInput2);  
  if(answer == "find"){  
     if(userInput.at(position) == string::npos){
        cout << userInput2 << " was not found.";  
     }else{  
        cout << userInput2 << " was found at position "<< position << "." << endl;
     }
```

I think the error might be right here:

```
position = userInput.find(userInput2);  
if(answer == "find"){  
 if(userInput.at(position) == string::npos){
    cout << userInput2 << " was not found.";  
 }else{  
    cout << userInput2 << " was found at position "<< position << "." << endl;
 }
```

Answer is find, find and userInput 2 is cheese which is supposed to return `userInput was not found` or `cheese was not found` but instead I'm getting this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 18446744073709551615) >= this->size() (which is 14)
```

Help me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userInput.at(position) == string::npos
```

will not do what you want, because if `position` is already `string::npos`, you're asking `string::at` to fetch a character from an invalid position. If you read the error message you've provided to us, you can see it is telling you this very fact: you're passing a crazy out of range value to `at` that is obviously waaaay bigger than the length of your string.

You should also read the docs for `string::find` (there are some [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)) which explicitly state that the function will **return npos if no such substring is found.**

Try just doing

```
if(position == string::npos){
```

instead.

Comment: @JoelJoseph if you have the same error then you clearly haven't removed the call to `userInput.at` and replaced it with `position`, as I suggested.

Comment: i did do that and still the same thing

Comment: @JoelJoseph Are you using different code to the stuff you've posted above? Because your error is about a `basic_string::at` call, and your code above contains a single mention of `basic_string::at` and my fix is about getting rid of that call. If you're getting an error about `basic_string::at` then either you're running code that you haven't shared with us, or you haven't made the change I've suggested, or you're getting a completely different error. You'll need to share some more details if you're not sure which of those possibilties is the right one.

Comment: There were some more code deeper in the program i didnt fix.

Comment: @JoelJoseph mystery solved ;-) Happy to be of assistance.